# UML class diagram association name for scope like relation

Tags: types, scope, uml, associations, terminology

how de we call and denote an association like one that child and parent scopes have?

```
+--------------------+                          +-------------------+
|    parent scope    | <――――――――――――――――――――――x |    child scope    |
+--------------------+                          +-------------------+
```

Parent to child association is clear, the parent is not allowed to access the child.

Child to parent association however is restricted, the child can't fully access the parent object, it only can lookup for a specific identifier, yet the identifier has to be missing in the child object.

Answer (score 1):

Your diagram means that the association is **navigable** from `Child scope` to `Parent scope`,  but that it is **not navigable** from the `Parent scope` to `Child scope`.

Navigation is about a promise of efficiency at run-time:

> Navigability means that instances participating in links at runtime (instances of an Association) can be accessed efficiently from instances at the other ends of the Association. The precise mechanism by which such efficient access is achieved is implementation specific. If an end is not navigable, access from the other ends may or may not be possible, and if it is, it might not be efficient.
> - UML 2.5.1 specifications.

So it is not a question of "being allowed", but about the ease and efficiency of such access.

There is however a mismatch between your diagram an the narrative. Assuming that navigability in your context is implemented with the use of an identifier with an efficient way to find back the instances of a class based on that identifier:

- navigability from `Child scope` to `Parent scope` means that the child would know the identifier of its parent.
- the non-navigability from `Parent scope` to `Child scope` would mean that the parent does not have the identifier of its children, and would have to find all the instances of the child class and ask the child who the parent is.  Extremely infefficient.

(Note that this is really impelmentation specific.  If you'd implement such a model in an RDBMS,  there would be no navigability issue,  since it is always easy and relatively efficient to query children based on their parent id.).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. Is there a term to indicate a 'partial' navigability? The child object can not fully navigate through the parent object

Comment: @Slev7n there is no specific term defined in the UML specifications.  "Unidirectional" vs "bidirectional" associations are commonly used and understood.  However it's slightly ambiguous (i.e. an association is always bidirectional in the sense that the inverse relationship is always defined independently of navigability): I'd rather recommend  "unidirectional" vs "bidirectional" navigability.

Answer (score -1):

From a business point of view (and so in a 'business use case'), there is no concept of navigability, this property is used for links between objects in O.O programming.
In a business use case, the direction of the arrow actually indicates which direction information flows after the lead actor triggers the use case. Most of the time, as there is 'interaction', information goes both ways (e.g. a screen sends information, visually, and receives it, by encoding, with mouse event, etc. If the information only goes one way, then the relationship is one-way.
For example, a use case sends data to a secondary actor (which is another system) and that system “consumes” that data WITHOUT ANY feedback.